# Arm Cortex-a9 timer triggered IRQ not clearing

Tags: c, timer, arm, qemu

I'm running a baremetal application in Qemu on a `xilinx-zynq-a9` machine. I'm
trying to leverage the private timer interrupt but am running into issues with
the interrupt re-triggering when I don't think it should be. I successfully
enable the private timer and sure enough my interrupt does trigger after
several seconds (like I expect it to), but then it never seems to re-trigger
continuously and not at the fixed interval I expect.

Just stepping through code with the debugger I *do* re-enter my main function
(although this *only* happens when I step through instruction by instruction,
letting it free-run it never seems to touch main again). I manually set-up the
IRQ, FIQ, and normal stack and thought initially that I was corrupting one of
them, but when I enter the IRQ (and when I leave it by manually stepping
through code) I see the `$sp` register is jumping back to the region of memory
I expect, the `cpsr` register reports that its in the appropriate mode (IRQ or
SVC depending).

I think this is because the GIC isn't de-asserting the interrupt even though I
think I'm doing it. Following an [irq example on
github](https://github.com/umanovskis/baremetal-arm/blob/ac090d8bfccb9abf6ce20c7de9729f7cda187838/src/07_interrupts/src/irq.c)
and [gic example on
github](https://github.com/umanovskis/baremetal-arm/blob/ac090d8bfccb9abf6ce20c7de9729f7cda187838/src/07_interrupts/src/gic.c) I do hit `irq_handler` when the private timer counts down the first time, and `isr()` is successfully executed:

```c
void __attribute__((interrupt("IRQ"))) irq_handler(void)
{
    uint16_t irq = gic_acknowledge_interrupt();
    isr_ptr isr = callback(irq);

    if (isr != NULL)
    {
        isr();
    }

    gic_end_interrupt(irq);
}
```

But even after acknowledging the interrupts, clearing the ISR of the timer, and
signaling the end of the interrupt (in that order) I essentially re-enter the
ISR immediately. Indeed, setting a breakpoint at address `0x18` where my vector
table lives is hit almost immediately.

```c
uint16_t gic_acknowledge_interrupt(void)
{
    // read from PERIPHBASE + 0x100 + 0x0C to
    // get pending interrupt. This seems correct and returns 29 (which is the
    // ID corresponding to the private timer ISR
    return gic_ifregs->ICCIAR & ICCIAR_ID_MASK; // ICCIAR_ID_MASK = 0x3FFFu
}
```

```c
static void ptimer_isr(void)
{
    // Write 0x1 to PERIPHBASE + 0x600 + 0x0C to clear interrupt
    WRITE32(pt_regs->timer_interrupt_status, 0x1);

    foo(); // do something
}
```

```c
void gic_end_interrupt(uint16_t number)
{
    // This is a WO register
    // Write ID(29 for private timer) to PERIPHBASE + 0x100 + 0x10 to clear interrupt
    WRITE32(gic_ifregs->ICCEOIR, (number & ICCEOIR_ID_MASK)); // ICCEOIR_ID_MASK = 0x3FFFu
}
```

Moreover, I've put the private timer into single shot mode and verified that it
does not start counting again after the first countdown event occurs. Even in
that case the IRQ handler is hit again.

I've even tried using the global timer instead of the private timer and I see the exact same behavior with it.

So in short:

- I seem to be properly enabling the private timer
- I seem to be properly enabling interrupts and registering the private timer
  interrupt with the GIC
- I do hit the IRQ handler when I expect to *the first time*
- If I step through with the debugger I *do* leave the IRQ for a bit, which
  leads to me believe my stack isn't corrupted or anything
- I re-enter the irq_handler unexpectedly and do still detect a pending
  interrupt with `gic_acknowledge_interrupt()` even though it should have been cleared

It's like the interrupt isn't being cleared, even though I think I'm doing
that, and the GIC is still signaling that the interrupt is pending, but I'm not
sure why.

## Edit:

### Adding trace

After adding `-d trace:gic*` to my QEMU invocation. I now see the behavior below. I'm not familiar with how to interpret tracepoints, but immediately after a write to `gic_end_interrupt()` I see `gic_update_bestirq cpu 0 irq 29 priority 0 cpu priority mask 248 cpu running priority 256` and
`gic_update_set_irq cpu[0]: irq = 1`. but NOT `gic_set_irq irq 29 level 1 cpumask 0x1 target 0x1`.

```
// Entry into irq_handler
gic_set_irq irq 29 level 1 cpumask 0x1 target 0x1
gic_update_bestirq cpu 0 irq 29 priority 0 cpu priority mask 248 cpu running priority 256
gic_update_set_irq cpu[0]: irq = 1

// gic_acknowledge_interrupt()
gic_acknowledge_irq cpu 0 acknowledged irq 29
gic_cpu_read cpu 0 iface read at 0x0000000c: 0x0000001d

// gic_end_interrupt()
gic_cpu_write cpu 0 iface write at 0x00000010 0x0000001d

// Why is this immeadietly set again?
gic_update_bestirq cpu 0 irq 29 priority 0 cpu priority mask 248 cpu running priority 256
gic_update_set_irq cpu[0]: irq = 1
```

### System Information

Additionally, for my system:

- Invoking `qemu-system-arm` with QEMU emulator version 8.0.2
- Running a bare-metal application on the `xilinx-zynq-a9` machine
- Compiled with `-march=armv7-a -marm`

### Timer configuration

I didn't add the entire source code here, but it should be enough to get an idea of what's happening. I borrowed some [from an example on github](https://github.com/umanovskis/baremetal-arm/blob/ac090d8bfccb9abf6ce20c7de9729f7cda187838/src/08_scheduler/src/ptimer.c) that uses QEMU and an interrupt successfully albeit w/ a different machine. Additionally, I've verified that the control register and the load register have the value I expect after configuration. I've also verified that the timer does start counting down and triggers an interrupt after the counter reaches zero (though again, I never seem to be able to clear the interrupt despite calling `WRITE32(pt_regs->timer_interrupt_status, 0x1);` when the interrupt is handled).

```
// using coprocessor to get PERIPHBASE
uint32_t cpu_get_periphbase(void) {
    uint32_t result;
    _asm("mrc p15, #4, %0, c15, c0, #0" : "=r" (result));
    return result;
}

#define PRIVATE_TIMER_OFFSET (0x600u) // offset per documentation
#define PT_BASE ((cpu_get_periphbase() + PRIVATE_TIMER_OFFSET))
```

```
error_code_t init_ptimer(
        const timer_auto_control_t continuous,
        const uint16_t clock_period_ms,
        const uint8_t prescaler,
        isr_ptr callback
        )
{

    // Validate clock_period_ms and prescaler is valid
    //...
    // Calculate load_value to put into load register

    pt_regs = (ptimer_registers*) PT_BASE;

    // Disable timer by writing 0 to first bit of 
    // PERIPHBASE + PRIVATE_TIMER_OFFSET + 0x8 (timer control register
    toggle_ptimer(TIMER_DISABLE);

    // Update load value
    WRITE32(pt_regs->timer_load, load_value);

    uint32_t control_reg_mask = 0;
    control_reg_mask |=
        (continuous << PRIVATE_AUTO_RELOAD_BIT_OFFSET) | // offset bit 1 of ctrl reg
        (prescaler << PRESCALER_BIT_OFFSET); // offset bit 8 of ctrl reg

    // Enable IRQ if that's desired
    if(callback != NULL)
    {
        control_reg_mask |=
            (0x1 << IRQ_ENABLE_BIT_OFFSET); // offset bit 2 of ctrl reg

        ptimer_isr_callback = callback;

        // register interrupt with irq handler
        irq_register_isr(
            PTIMER_INTERRUPT_ID,
            ptimer_isr);
    }

    // Update control register
    WRITE32(pt_regs->timer_control, control_reg_mask);

    return NO_ERR;
}
```

Comment: You can turn on the tracepoints in the GIC ("-d trace:gic*" on the command line) which might help in providing insight about what QEMU's GIC model thinks it is doing with interrupts. Sadly the mptimer device model doesn't have tracepoints (you could add some if you felt like messing with QEMU internals).

Comment: Oh wow, I'm pretty new to QEMU and didn't know about that feature. I just tried it out and it does give me some content that I'll parse through. Thanks!

Comment: It's basically just "print statements in the code that you can turn on at runtime". How helpful the tracing is depends a bit on how thorough the person putting in the tracepoints was. Sometimes it's a bit cryptic unless you also look at the source code to see what exactly the tracepoint is doing...

Comment: I see in the trace that there's no gic_set_irq trace for the irq line going to "level 0" -- so I think that means the timer device is still holding the interrupt high, which is why it remains pending after you EOI it.

Comment: Detail about how you are programming the timer would help here I think

Comment: @PeterMaydell yeah I agree that it looks like the timer device is holding the interrupt high. I've added some snippets of my timer configuration code to help clarify how I'm initializing the peripheral.

Comment: so you went through the natural progression of learning the timer, without any interrupts, then learning the timer through polling the timer, including enabling, firing and clearing the interrupt (with the gic and processor interrupts disabled) Then allowing the interrupt into the gic (still polling) and clearing.  THEN once that is all mastered actually enabling it to the processor?   and with all of that enabling to the processor broke it all?

Comment: please provide a complete minimal example, including all your stack setup, etc.

Comment: @old_timer I didn't do everything in that exact order no, but I did look at the timer independently of the gic, then enabled interrupts and then the gic. It will take me a bit to put together an example. Thanks.

Comment: for designs where you can long before you release the interrupt to the processor core it is significantly easier to poll your way through it...using...throwaway code specifically made just for learning that peripheral.  takes many times longer trying to do everything at once.

Comment: also understand that you are running on qemu yes?  which means you cant assume they completely implemented the logic (and that it may not work the same on real hardware).  It depends on the emulation...so it might not match the docs for the real hardware.  on the good side you can go into the qemu source code and see what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out an answer after finding someone having a similar problem on github. It turns out that the ISR wasn't being cleared b/c I was illegally accessing the register to clear it.

Their suggestion was to use the `-d guest_errors` option in QEMU. Stepping through the code when I attempted to clear the interrupt via a pointer to my pack struct in my isr call back `ptimer_isr`.

```
typedef volatile struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    uint32_t timer_load;             /* 0x0 */
    uint32_t timer_counter;          /* 0x4 */
    uint32_t timer_control;          /* 0x8 */
    uint32_t timer_interrupt_status; /* 0xC */
} ptimer_registers;
```

```
static void ptimer_isr(void)
{
    // Write 0x1 to PERIPHBASE + 0x600 + 0x0C to clear interrupt
    WRITE32(pt_regs->timer_interrupt_status, 0x1);

    foo(); // do something
}
```

I got the following complaint from QEMU:

```
Invalid write at addr 0x20E, size 1, region '(null)', reason: rejected
Invalid read at addr 0xF, size 1, region 'arm_mptimer_timer', reason: invalid size (min:4 max:4)
```

This looks like a complaint about byte-size access. Dumping the object code for my isr callback does show a bunch of byte-sized access instructions `ldrb` and `strb`.

```
00000bf4 <ptimer_isr>:
     bf4:       e92d4800        push    {fp, lr}
     bf8:       e28db004        add     fp, sp, #4
     bfc:       e30038d8        movw    r3, #2264       ; 0x8d8
     c00:       e3403030        movt    r3, #48 ; 0x30
     c04:       e5933000        ldr     r3, [r3]
     c08:       e5d3200c        ldrb    r2, [r3, #12]
     c0c:       e3a02000        mov     r2, #0
     c10:       e3822001        orr     r2, r2, #1
     c14:       e5c3200c        strb    r2, [r3, #12]
     c18:       e5d3200d        ldrb    r2, [r3, #13]
     c1c:       e3a02000        mov     r2, #0
     c20:       e5c3200d        strb    r2, [r3, #13]
     c24:       e5d3200e        ldrb    r2, [r3, #14]
     c28:       e3a02000        mov     r2, #0
     c2c:       e5c3200e        strb    r2, [r3, #14]
     c30:       e5d3200f        ldrb    r2, [r3, #15]
     c34:       e3a02000        mov     r2, #0
     c38:       e5c3200f        strb    r2, [r3, #15]
     c3c:       ebffffc0        bl      b44 <tick>
     c40:       e30038e0        movw    r3, #2272       ; 0x8e0
     c44:       e3403030        movt    r3, #48 ; 0x30
     c48:       e5933000        ldr     r3, [r3]
     c4c:       e12fff33        blx     r3
     c50:       e320f000        nop     {0}
     c54:       e8bd8800        pop     {fp, pc}
```

I changed the struct definition in order to force 32-bit alignment:

```
typedef volatile struct __attribute__((packed, aligned(4))) {
    uint32_t timer_load;             /* 0x0 */
    uint32_t timer_counter;          /* 0x4 */
    uint32_t timer_control;          /* 0x8 */
    uint32_t timer_interrupt_status; /* 0xC */
} ptimer_registers;
```

and wrote a function which should ensure word-wise access instead of my `#define WRITE32(_reg, _val) (*(volatile uint32_t*)&_reg = _val)` macro.

```
static inline void write_reg32(
        uint32_t volatile* const reg,
        uint32_t const value )
{
    *reg = value;
}
```

```
static void ptimer_isr(void)
{
    // Write 0x1 to PERIPHBASE + 0x600 + 0x0C to clear interrupt
    write_reg32(&(pt_regs->timer_interrupt_status), 0x1);

    foo(); // do something
}
```

Now all the byte-wise access instructions are gone, and my code works as epxected.

```
00000c24 <ptimer_isr>:
     c24:       e92d4800        push    {fp, lr}
     c28:       e28db004        add     fp, sp, #4
     c2c:       e30038d8        movw    r3, #2264       ; 0x8d8
     c30:       e3403030        movt    r3, #48 ; 0x30
     c34:       e5933000        ldr     r3, [r3]
     c38:       e283300c        add     r3, r3, #12
     c3c:       e3a01001        mov     r1, #1
     c40:       e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
     c44:       ebffffbe        bl      b44 <write_reg32>
     c48:       ebffffc9        bl      b74 <tick>
     c4c:       e30038e0        movw    r3, #2272       ; 0x8e0
     c50:       e3403030        movt    r3, #48 ; 0x30
     c54:       e5933000        ldr     r3, [r3]
     c58:       e12fff33        blx     r3
     c5c:       e320f000        nop     {0}
     c60:       e8bd8800        pop     {fp, pc}

00000b44 <write_reg32>:
     b44:       e52db004        push    {fp}            ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
     b48:       e28db000        add     fp, sp, #0
     b4c:       e24dd00c        sub     sp, sp, #12
     b50:       e50b0008        str     r0, [fp, #-8]
     b54:       e50b100c        str     r1, [fp, #-12]
     b58:       e51b3008        ldr     r3, [fp, #-8]
     b5c:       e51b200c        ldr     r2, [fp, #-12]
     b60:       e5832000        str     r2, [r3]
     b64:       e320f000        nop     {0}
     b68:       e28bd000        add     sp, fp, #0
     b6c:       e49db004        pop     {fp}            ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
     b70:       e12fff1e        bx      lr
```

Comment: Glad you figured out the problem. "attribute(packed)" is a bit of a bear trap...